# How to extract data at a specific location from a file containing a grid of data points

Tags: awk, extract

I have a file containing a 3D grid (x, y, time), with a property "v" at each grid point. I want to extract the time profile of "v" at a particular x, y point, or more specifically, at the x, y point closest to my desired location (it is unlikely that the desired location will exactly fall on a grid point). Is there an easy awk script for this when the file is in either ascii or binary format?

Example of file format

```
X   Y   Time   V
1   1     0    2
1   1    10    3
1   1    20    4
1   2     0    3
1   2    10    8
1   2    20   11
1   3     0    3
```

Example of desired output if location of interest is `x=0.9, y=2.1`

```
1   2     0    3
1   2    10    8
1   2    20   11
```

Comment: Could show an example of how your file is formatted?

Comment: If the given point is "0.5 0.5 5", which entry do you want to find?

Comment: In that situation I wouldn't really mind. I'd be happy with either the first entry in the file that meets a certain criteria or the smallest or largest one

Comment: Just reread my reply to twalberg and realised I may not have answered fully. I wish to locate a point and then extract the data for all time values at that point. Hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk                           
function abs(val) { return (val < 0 ? -val : val) }

BEGIN { ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ }

NR==FNR {
    if (NR>1) {
        dist[NR] = abs(x - $1) + abs(y - $2)
        min = (NR==2 || dist[NR]<min ? dist[NR] : min)
    }
    next
}

FNR==1 || dist[FNR] == min

$ awk -v x=0.9 -v y=2.1 -f tst.awk file
X   Y   Time   V
1   2     0    3
1   2    10    8
1   2    20   11
```

Just check that the algorithm to calculate `dist[]` is what you need and tweak it to suit otherwise.

Comment: youre welcome. remember to click on the check mark next to the answer if/when you accept it.

Comment: @EdMorton can you please explain `BEGIN { ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ }` for me? thanks!

Comment: Sure - ARGV is the array or arguments starting at index zero with the command name (`awk`) and ARGC is the count of the number of values stored in ARGV so if there were no file name arguments given on the command line then ARGC would be 1 because `ARGV[0] = awk`. If you pass awk a file name `awk 'script' file` then ARGV[0]=awk and ARGV[1]=file and ARGC=2. So, to parse a file twice without specifying it twice on the command line `awk 'script' file file` all you need to do is copy last entry from ARGV into the next position in the array `ARGV[2] = ARGV[1]` and increase the arg count `ARGC++`.

Comment: script is clean,  explanation is  clear , Thank you! @EdMorton